# Interpretation of fast fourier transform in a simple time series

Tags: interpretation, fourier-transform

I am struggling with understanding the result of FFT in R. I have 729 observations, two years data. In the data I simulated there were more visitors every sunday.
I divided 729/7 which is approximately 104. And there was a peak indeed, but also two others, which I didn't get. I see that they are at possitions ~104 x 2 and ~104 x 3. But I totally lack an intution behind it.

Then, when I put the peak every first day of the month, I had even more peaks. I am not sure where to look for the explanation.
Below is the complete code. It contains simulated data and all of the steps:

```
# Setting the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

# Define the start and end date
start_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2022-12-30")

# Creating a date sequence
dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "day")

# Creating a data frame
# month version
park_data <- data.frame(
  date = dates,
  visits = ifelse(lubridate::day(dates) %in% c(1), 
                  rnorm(1, 1500, 100), rnorm(1, 400, 100)
                  )
)
# sunday version
park_data <- data.frame(
  date = dates,
  visits = ifelse(weekdays(dates) %in% c("sunday"), 
                  rnorm(1, 1500, 100), rnorm(1, 400, 100)
                  )
)

# Preparing data for FFT
fft_data <- park_data$visits - mean(park_data$visits)  # removing the constant component
fft_data <- fft_data

# Perform FFT
fft_result <- fft(fft_data)

# Calculate amplitude
fft_amp <- Mod(fft_result)[1:(length(fft_data)/2)]  

# Calculate frequency
fft_freq <- (0:(length(fft_amp) - 1)) / length(fft_data)

# Create a data frame for the plot
fft_df <- data.frame(
  freq = fft_freq,
  amp = fft_amp
)

# Drawing the plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(fft_df, aes(x = freq, y = amp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 104/length(fft_data), linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Frequency", y = "Amplitude", 
       title = "FFT Result for Park Visit Count")
```

[image]
I couldn't find any similar questions. Please, share your advice.

Comment: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section3_3/Sec3_3.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier Transform decomposes a signal into a series of sine and cosine curves. You could obtain a single peak in the spectrum (in the FFT-transformed data) **only** if your signal were a pure (co)sine. This is not the case for your data, hence you get the "higher harmonics".

Comment: I read that term somewhere! - "higher harmonics" :) How can I predict how many of them will appear? How can I interpret them?

Comment: Re: Predicting: Other than performing the FFT, your best bet is to visually inspect the time series (the curve): The more it deviates from a perfect sine, the more pronounced the harmonics. Re: Interpretation: The same in the opposite direction: More - and more pronounced - harmonics imply a larger deviation from a simple sine curve. That's actually basic signal processing (probably too basic to be asked on the signal processing stack exchange).

Comment: Oh... Right. Will they often appear "later" or "after" the main peak I was interested in? 
I think I should study some basic signal processing then. Thank you.

Comment: As a rule, yes. Otherwise we wouldn't be calling them *higher* harmonics. "*Higher*" refers here to the frequency.